# Использование if в цикле for в шаблонах Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте.

Есть следующий код:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for node in services %}
    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
      <div class="{% if services.count > 2 %}col-sm-4{% elif services.count == 2 %}col-sm-6{% else %}col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3{% endif %}">
        <div class="features-box">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Где `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}` закрывает `<div class="row">` и открывает заново, каждое третье повторение в цикле, чтобы сетка оставалась ровной.

Проблема в том, что проверка условий находится внутри цикла, количество итераций цикла не меняется, вне зависимости от того, было ли соблюдено условие, или нет.

На деле, это приводит к тому, что в одном из `<div class="row"></div>` может находится только 1 элемент, когда их должно быть 3.

При попытке сделать что-то вроде `{% for node in services if not node.is_leaf_node %}` получаю следующую ошибку :

> 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for node in
>   services if not node.is_leaf_node

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Пришлось изменять `queryset`, поскольку в шаблоне сделать то что нужно по человечески не представляется возможным, или же я не нашёл лучшего варианта.

Comment: дак либо модель данных сформируйте таким образом, чтобы в массив попадли только нужные элементы. либо перед циклом заведите отдельный счетчик, который крутить будете в if-е и используйте его вместо встроенного/

Comment: @teran, я отдаю все нужные элементы, здесь важно именно отображение элементов с определённой логикой.
По поводу счётчика, не совсем понял.

Comment: я с используемыми технологиями и синтаксисом не знаком, но перед циклом заведите какой нить `{% idx = 0 %}`, внутри if-а инкрементируйте его, и  его же проверяйте вместо `forloop.counter`

Comment: типа `{% if idx++|divisibleby:3 %}`

Answer (score 0):

Бутстрап сам перенесёт блоки правильно, если обеспечить им одинаковую высоту.
Соответственно, кусок кода с добавлением row не нужен.

Другой вариант: в css делать `clear` для каждого третьего элемента:

```css
.diffrent-heights > .row > .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel=stylesheet href=//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css>

<section class=container-fluid>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col-xs-4>1</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>2</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>3</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>4</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>5</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>6</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>7</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>8</div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid diffrent-heights">
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col-xs-4>1</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>2<br>2</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>3</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>4<br>4</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>5</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>6</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>7</div>
    <div class=col-xs-4>8<br>8</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Блоки разной высоты. Нужно для трёх элементов делать один row

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik дак второй вариант с css-правилами чем вас не устраивает?